# rewrite rules problem with #comments-2345

Tags: rewrite-rules

I am trying to created new rewrite rules for sth like this

```
www.myweb.com/question/#comments-2345
```

where 'question' is TAG and the #comments-2345 suppose to be recognized and read by get_query_var. '#comments-" is always constant string and the 2345 depends on the comment number in db. 
code

```
add_rewrite_tag('%question%', '([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^question/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=77&question=$matches[1]','top');
```

and i read the the variable as

```
$hpytanie= get_query_var( 'question' );
```

But something does not work, the get_query_var gives empty. Any advice why it does not work?

thanks

Comment: try this link without #

Comment: www.myweb.com/question/comments-2345

Comment: it has to be with #, as this is the comment structure format. This page has comments, and if i call the page then list of the comments is generated with the links to the parent comment only. But when i call the page/#comment-333 then only this parent comment with children is displayed.

Comment: `get_query_var()` works on query strings only, and not URL hash like that.

Comment: would be possible to rewrite differently with the "#comments-"  before ??
add_rewrite_rule('^question/#comments-([^/]*)/?',', 'index.php?page_id=77&question=$matches[1]','top');

Comment: add_filter('query_vars', 'foo_my_query_vars');
function foo_my_query_vars($vars){ 
    $vars[] = 'question';
    return $vars;
}

Comment: what this filter do? can read #comments-2345 to the string by get_query_var()??

Comment: Your rewrite rule works with `/question/slug` where `get_query_var()` would give you the `slug`. But with `/question/#slug`, `get_query_var()` would instead return `''` (i.e. empty string). If you want to access the URL hash, use JavaScript: `location.hash`.

Comment: i do not use JS so it has to be only with php. Would be possible to have sth like /question/#comments-SLUG, where only SLUG is read by get_query_var()??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2317523/9217760

Comment: @GregSkala `/question/comments-SLUG` is possible, but not with the hash symbol (`#`).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a query var

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'foo_my_query_vars'); 
function foo_my_query_vars($vars){ 
  $vars[] = 'question'; return $vars; 
}
```